# Duplicate symbol with bazel build with envoy proxy

Tags: bazel, envoyproxy, bazel-rules, bazel-cpp

We customize envoy proxy by create a new filter. We are using envoy proxy with Version v1.21.2 and it build and link success fully without any problem.

Now we want to upgrade the envoy to latest version(which is v1.26.2). But after build successfully, **it produces some weird link errors - more than 4000 duplicated symbol error.**

Could you please help to point out the possibilities of wrong configuration that we've made? Thank you very much!

**We are using bazel build C++/go(v 6.1.0).**

following is extracted from the error log:

```
duplicate symbol 'vtable for Envoy::Network::Address::EnvoyInternalInstance' in:
bazel-out/darwin_arm64-dbg-ST-1dd6bf738d96/bin/external/envoy/source/common/network/libaddress_lib.lo(address_impl.o)
bazel-out/darwin_arm64-dbg/bin/external/envoy/source/common/network/libaddress_lib.lo(address_impl.o)
```

duplicate symbol 'typeinfo name for Envoy::Network::Address::EnvoyInternalInstance' in:
bazel-out/darwin_arm64-dbg-ST-1dd6bf738d96/bin/external/envoy/source/common/network/libaddress_lib.lo(address_impl.o)
bazel-out/darwin_arm64-dbg/bin/external/envoy/source/common/network/libaddress_lib.lo(address_impl.o)

Comment: the weird thing is that the libraries are generated twice in both foder `bazel-out/darwin_arm64-dbg` and `bazel-out/darwin_arm64-dbg-ST-1dd6bf738d96`